# How to insert spacing in formula?

Tags: spacing, equations

My code is like this:

```
\begin{equation}
Specific Yield=  \frac{Actual Energy From the Plant(kWh)}{Total Plant Capacity (kWp)}
\end{equation}
```

It came like this: [image]

[image]

Comment: What unit is “kWp”?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please note that the code you post in your questions should always be a complete compilable [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050) (so it should start at `\documentclass` and end at `\end{document}` being as minimal as possible) -- just for the future.

Comment: @egreg It seems to be kilo watt-hour. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/44796/confused-about-unit-of-kilowatt-hours

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the expressions you use in your formula are text, I'd strongly recommend using `\text` in the formula (provided by `amsmath`):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \text{Specific Yield} = 
  \frac{\text{Actual Energy From the Plant (kWh)}}
    {\text{Total Plant Capacity (kWp)}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think there should be a space between "Plant" and "(kWh)", though.

Comment: @Mico thought the same, but I only used the input of OP :)

Comment: @user146864 if so, you should accept my answer (by hitting this grey tick), if you think enough time has passed and you'll get no better answers (and I don't think you'll get better answers for this question to be honest).

Comment: Ok, done. I am a begineer so i dont have much ideas. TYSM

Comment: @user146864 no problem, we all were once beginners (except for [egreg](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg))